# Second order matricial equation - General form

Tags: matrices

I attempt to solve the following equation, but I fail. It is a generic case for the scalar second order equation, which solution stams from the mathematician Bhàskara.

$\sum_{jk}^p a_{ijk}  \, x_j \, x_k + b_i^{\intercal} \, x + c_i = 0$, $c_i \in \mathbb{R}$, $b_i^\intercal \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $i = 1, \cdots, n$.

Some remarks of the equation I attempted to solve comes from mere intuition:

$\sum_{ij}^p a_{ij}  \, x_i \, x_j \triangleq x^\intercal \, A_i \, x$

Now I try to undertand what does the relation below means. Is it possible to expand it into different form

\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
x^\intercal \, A_1 \, x \\
\vdots \\
x^\intercal \, A_m \, x
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

Two remarkable literature are in [here](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/325701) and [here](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/58527) about where does the equation appears, not the way I formulate here, but similarly. I hope it is compreehensible. If not, please, ask me for more information.

I thank in advance.
Best regards,
Bruno

Comment: Why do you insist on saying "retards" instead of "regards"?

Comment: T near to G on keyboard